# How to implement a generic service class in java Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have many services that have repeated code and I want to know how to implement a generic service so all my services can extend it.

Service interfaces example (**Repeated code**):

```
@Service
public interface IUserService{    
    List<User> findAll();
    User save(User entity);
    User findById(long id);
    void delete(User entity);
    void deleteById(long id);
    long count();
}
```

---

```
@Service
public interface IEventService{ 

    List<Event> findAll();
    Event save(Event entity);
    Event findById(long id);
    void delete(Event entity);
    void deleteById(long id);
    long count();
}
```

And their implementations (**Now, I have the same code in all the implementations**):

```
@Service
public class EventService implements IEventService{

    @Autowired
    private IEventDao dao;

    @Override
    public List<Event> findAll() {
        return dao.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Event save(Event entity) {
        return dao.save(entity);
    }

   Other CRUD methods...

}
```

---

```
@Service
    public class UserService implements IUserService{

        @Autowired
        private IUserDao dao;

        @Override
        public List<User> findAll() {
            return dao.findAll();
        }

        @Override
        public User save(User entity) {
            return dao.save(entity);
        }

       Other CRUD methods...

    }
```

Comment: @ChrisTurner, all it means is that the DAO also needs to be generic. Updated the example.

Comment: Do the services simply expose the underlying dao, method for method, with no other business logic etc?  If so, then why bother?

Comment: @RobertMoskal, I'm sure the real implementation is much more complex :)

Comment: Yes, the real implementation is more conplex. This is just an example.

Comment: @metacubed how do I implement the generic DAO?

Comment: @Luis-OrlandoGuzman, if you use Spring Data, the underlying classes like `TypedQuery`, `JdbcTemplate` are all generic. So you can pass in the type. If you get stuck with some specific step, feel free to post another question for that issue so we can help you.

Comment: @metacubed I have an idea of how to implement a generic DAO but, my question is: What will be the generic Entity <E> to use in that generic DAO?

Answer (score 27):

This is fairly straightforward using [Java generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). You can replace the actual class `User`, `Event`, etc. with a type parameter.

```
public interface IGenericService<T> {    
    List<T> findAll();
    T save(T entity);
    T findById(long id);
    void delete(T entity);
    void deleteById(long id);
    long count();
}
```

Then do the same for the implementation:

```
public class GenericService<T> implements IGenericService<T> {

    // The DAO class will also need to be generic,
    // so that it can use the right class types
    @Autowired
    private IDao<T> dao;

    @Override
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return dao.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public T save(T entity) {
        return dao.save(entity);
    }

    // Other CRUD methods...

}
```

Even further, you can also create your actual services as:

```
@Service
class UserService extends GenericService<User> { }

@Service
class EventService extends GenericService<Event> { }
```

Here's a good tutorial from the Java documentation: [Learning the Java Language: Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Another one with good examples: [The Basics of Java Generics](http://www.baeldung.com/java-generics)

Comment: Does this approach actually deduplicate the code at all?

Comment: @RobertMoskal, hmm, I'm not sure what you mean. It does deduplicate User vs Event services. And I'm sure the real code is much more complex.

Comment: @RobertMoskal, I'll clarify the answer a bit more. Thanks!