# Design classes using Spring boot, JPA using callbacks of generic type

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, spring-data-jpa, callback

I'm confused about the design using Spring boot and JPA when callbacks are involved.

Example:

Controller will call the Service class and pass in the value of T, i.e Employee in our example:

```
@Controller
public class Controller1{
 
 @Autowired
 Service1 service1;

 @RequestMapping("/employee")
  public ResponseEntity<Object> employees(Request request){
    //Since employee is called I know that T should be of type Employee
    service1.runService(new Employee()); //I want to pass the type T as 
                                       //Employee, so that in the 
                                       //database all Employees can be saved
  }


}
```

I have a service:

```
//Controller will call this service and pass in T type
@Service
public class Service1{
  @Autowired
  Dependency1 dependency1;

 //@Autowire CallbackImpl -> this won't work because I need to create a new 
 //                          instance of type T for each different request from 
 //                            controller


public void runService(T t){
//CallbackImpl<Employee> callbackImpl= new CallbackImpl<>();-> this won't work because 
                                       //           it is not managed by Spring
                                       //           and the Repository bean 
                                       //           throws null pointer exception
  
   //Here I want to invoke the callbackImpl<T> class and specify the type T.. 
   // ..(which will be  an Entity type)
  
  ThirdPartyClass.get(callbackImpl) // callbackImpl is of type T (i.e Employee 
                                    // in this example)
 }
}
```

This ThirdPartyClass.get() method provides an interface IThirdPartyCallback.

My class CallbackImpl implements this interface, gets the values and saves it to database like this:

```
CallbackImpl<T> implements IThirdPartyCallback{
 
@Autowired
BaseRepository<T, Long> baseRepository // The sub-class EmployeeRepository 
                                       //..that 
                                      //..implements BaseRepository is called 
                                      //..based on type T

@Override
public void callback(String result){
// convert result to List<T> type, in this example T is Employee

baseRepository.saveAll(listOfResultsOfTypeT);  //in this result will be converted to List<T> 
                                 //and saved. In this example result will be 
                                 // List<Employee>
}
  }
```

I need multiple instances/beans of CallbackImpl. What would be a recommended wat to achieve that?

1. I could create a Factory with a @Configuration, and have a method return a new CallbackImpl bean for every request
2. Perhaps I could remove Autowired from the BaseRepository, and pass in the BaseRepository through the Service -> Is this a good design? i.e Repository should be only defined in Service and the Service passes around the Repository  bean with helper classes when needed?
3. Declare the CallbackImpl as prototype scope. It's not clear to me how I will call create new instances each time with a different type T using this approach.
4. Perhaps I can create N repositories with N services for N entities that I want to save in the database tables. And have N controllers as well, so this entire problem is eliminated, but this looks like a lot of similar code repeated, if all I'm doing is saving different types of entities like Employee, Contractor, Chair etc. i.e unrelated entities.
5. Use EntityManger somehow to persist different entities

Or is this completely bonkers and there is a much better way to get what I want using a much better or simpler design?

Comment: @xerx593 user:592355 https://stackoverflow.com/users/592355/xerx593 what happened? :/

Comment: Sorry, I deleted, but hope you still have the "useful links"...going deeper, I started to doubt my answer/approach

Comment: Yes, I think so. Basically I am getting different Entities from the third party class, depending on what request(Entity) is passed to the third party class from the controller. And I want to save all this list of Entities in the database. Each Entity can have its own table. So when /employee is called, the third party class wil return a list of Employees, and I want to save it to the Employee database table. When Contractor is called, I get back a list of contractors and I want to save them to the database tabe Contractor.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/xerx593/demo-generic-mj) we can play :)

Comment: so first of all, we should clarify/identify: do we need "prototype" scope? (since that complicates some) ... for "generic bean" (definitions), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51624481/592355) is sweat!

Comment: Going through your example and tyring to understand it..I was thinking to simplify things we don't need the CallbackImpl to be a Spring managed bean? It can be a simple java class with type T. The common service will call this class and pass in the type T. The Employee service will call in the common service and pass in type T. I only want to save the entities, so I have EmployeeRepository in EmployeeService, and pass it to the common service, which passes it to the CallBackImpl, which does a saveAll(employees). If that makes sense. Will read up on ObjectProvider to understand your code

Comment: in test i use it (ObjectProvider with according generic parameter) only as a "collection" of all services, elsewhere i use it to obtain "fresh prototypes"